# Eclipse JSF auto complete

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jsf-2, mojarra

I have Eclipse Juno on Linux (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)
This is my version:

Version: Juno Service Release 1
Build id: 20121004-1855

On OSX 10.8.2 I have:

Version: Juno Release
Build id: 20120614-1722

When I am editing an xhtml file for JSF I get auto complete of my JSF beans on both, which is awesome, but the auto complete on OSX is much better. Here are a few differences:

Mac: Start auto complete anywhere, it will fill #{} for you.

Linux: Only start auto complete inside #{}.

Mac: Auto complete of objects returned by beans, for example on a ui:repeat my var="object" can be used for auto complete.

Linux: Not available.

Is there some reason for this behavior? is it maybe something to do with my project setup? because of different work environments they are different projects. Both the projects are using JSF 2.1 as a project facet, both using mojarra, not sure if that makes a difference.

Thanks.

Comment: it's probably related to what Eclipse plugins you have installed. Do you use [JBoss Tools](https://www.jboss.org/tools) installed?

Comment: I started thinking about that, on my Mac I recently installed and uninstalled JBoss Studio, JBoss tools and the glassfish plugin, maybe even some spring plugin. I went to my linux, installed JBoss tools and studio and glassfish and it didn't help. It is just so much nicer to write JSF code on my mac at this point I'm willing to install almost anything!

Comment: @mntgoat didja ever figure something out? it'd be **so** nice if autocomplete inside ui:repeat worked

Comment: No I did not. I think it was maybe a jboss plugin or spring, or something else but I tried matching everything I had on my mac on my linux machine and still it would never work. I have now switched to IntelliJ which gives you auto complete for everything I have thought to try so far.